# Ring of formal power series in Macaulay2

Tags: power-series, computer-algebra-systems, formal-power-series, macaulay2

How does one define the ring $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ of formal power series in two variables over $\mathbb{C}$ in Macaulay2? Or Singular? I have seen some papers that claim to perform calculations in Macaulay2 with modules over formal power series rings, but they do not explain how.

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/macaulay2/8hd9YeLaZ8M) seems to give code for Singular.

Comment: @Mark I can't really glean much from the link you suggested. Where is the Singular code on that webpage? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Ashwin,

As mentioned by David Eisenbud on the Mark's [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/macaulay2/8hd9YeLaZ8M), Singular is optimised for local ordering.

In Singular you can define something called as local ordering. For example, the following `Singular` code might help you:

`ring r = 0, (x,y,z), ds;`

For more details and examples, have a look at [Singular help](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-1-0/sing_839.htm).

Hope this helps!

-- Mike